# "Release file is not valid yet" and other errors when running apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Legion Y520 (16 GB RAM, 7th generation i7-7700HQ processor). When I run the `apt-get update` command, I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Ign:3 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/arx/release/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                  
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]                                         
Hit:6 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Release                                                                    
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [83.2 kB]                                                          
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                       
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                     
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libretro/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                        
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micove/console/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/minetestdevs/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micove/console/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcsx2-team/pcsx2-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15.9 kB]
Reading package lists... Done     
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 38min 48s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 38min 53s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 39min 9s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/micove/console/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Release file for http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcsx2-team/pcsx2-daily/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3h 41min 24s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

The thing is, whenever I try to add a repository recently, I get the same error: Release file is not valid, and that updating from such a repository  can't be done securely. At first, I thought the repository/program is outdated, but even popular programs like Retroarch gives me the same error. I tried at least 5 different ones, all the same.

Here is my `sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
##'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
#deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

I've been searching for a solution for the past week, and couldn't find any. Please make your answer as much "noob-friendly" as possible, I'm still learning.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I opened up the first I saw (http://ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu/dists/) looking at what releases are supported; and bionic (18.04) isn't there (ie. isn't supported).  Your solution is to comment it out, or remove it and then find another 'fix' for whatever reason you added it. Using it with your release isn't very *noob-friendly* as it risks issues so finding a replacement is easist.

Comment: @guiverc Ohh okay. How did you know 18.04 isn't supported? I entered that link but couldn't find any info. Should I remove all the ppas that gives errors? And how do I check before adding new ones? Thank you.

Comment: Marcellus - look at the link I posted; you'll see a list of directories the names of which are the supported releases using names, so 18.04 is bionic, 16.04 is xenial (*xenial is there so 16.04 is supported*) etc.  Compare my link with the one from your error listing (*which is where I got the link from!*) & you'll work it out I bet.

Comment: @guiverc Ohh okay! i didn't know each version had a different name! Thank you very much!

Comment: fyi: if you look at the line in your sources (or you can look at the output of the paste as well) you'll note the distro-name on each line (constant refs. to bionic tell me you're on 18.04)....  *this is to help you learn, [but is also a clue with regard my first comment ending; suggestion: learn the risks/consequences first as its not for noobs; you have to do your homework to keep away from dep-hell]...*

Comment: @guiverc I opened up "Software & Updates" and removed all the sources that aren't supported by bionic. Now everything works amazing. Thank you so much for your help. If you want, post the info you gave me as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened up the first I saw (http://ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu/dists/) looking at what releases are supported; and bionic (18.04) isn't there (ie. isn't supported).

Your solution is to comment it out, or remove it (refer [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) for more info [provided by karel]) and then find another 'fix' for whatever reason you added it.

Using that source with your release isn't very noob-friendly as it risks issues so finding a replacement is easiest

FYI: The link I provided was from your output, I just navigated to the dists/ folder where each supported release is visible (by name, 18.04 is bionic, 16.04 is xenial (*xenial is there so 16.04 is supported*) etc).